# grails domain default sort by last updated field

Tags: mysql, sorting, grails, grails-orm, relationship

I have a grails domain hasMany and belongsTo relationship as the below :

I am wanting to sort based on 'Submission' 'lastUpdated' 'desc'

```
class User {
  String username
  String password

  static hasMany = [ submissions: Submission ]

  static mapping = {
     sort submissions: 'desc'  // This doesn't do anything?
  }
}

class Submission {
  String reference
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

  static belongsTo = User
}
```

So everytime I collect a User's submissions, I would like it default sorted as lastUpdated desc. The equivalent mysql statement would be the following

```
select (fields) from submission order by last_updated desc;
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks greatly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read [how to set default sort order in assosiation](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#defaultSortOrder)

From GORM documentation

> Finally, you can configure sorting at the association level:

```
class Airport {
    ...
    static hasMany = [flights: Flight]

    static mapping = {
        flights sort: 'number', order: 'desc'
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks, when i add the recommended code I get the following: [User->submissions] are not supported with unidirectional one to many relationships. Any ideas?

Comment: i not sure, in your domain class you use an unidirectional association but try instead of **static belongsTo = User** use **static belongsTo = [user:User]** to implement a bidirectional association

Comment: The link doesn't have anything to do with sorting anymore.

Comment: Thank you for notifying, I will correct the link. Answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a unidirectional relationship, the following solution works perfectly!

```
class User {
  String username
  String password

  SortedSet submissions

  static hasMany = [ submissions: Submission ]

}

class Submission implements Comparable {
  String reference
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

  static belongsTo = User

  @Override
  public int compareTo(obj) {
        obj.lastUpdated.compareTo(lastUpdated)
  } 

}
```